# Windows 10 recovery

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I want to create an automated task using powershell. The idea of the task is that i start my PC using WOL, it creates a recovery iso and stores it on my NAS. After the iso is created and stored, the PC shuts down.

The wol and shutdown part are already done.

Now i was wondering if the iso part is possible? So that i can create a recovery image stored on an external place. And if there are problems with my pc. I can restore the image i created.

Hope you guys can help me with my question.
Many thanks

Comment: Does it have to be an ISO image? I guess just creating an Image Backup (Win 7 style) would be way easier and basically cover your requirements.

Comment: I was thinking to flash the iso to a USB and then put it in my pc as a recovery stick.

Comment: Should work just the same with an ootb Image Backup.